# Maximum or minimum in a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I Have a function that doesn't exit on (0,0). I want to apply second derived criteria, to this function, to know if that point is maximum or minimum, but the second derived doesn't exits on (0,0) either. I know is a critical point but is not either a maximum or a minimum. So what is it? The function is $$f(x, y) = xy + \frac1x + \frac1y$$

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. what is the function?

Comment: if the function is not defined at $(0,0)$, then that point can't be min. or max. What is the function?

Comment: The function is f(x, y) = xy +(1/x)+(1/y)

Comment: You can calculate the partial derivative with respect to $x,y$ for this function.

Comment: @NoChance yes, i can. and after that how can I know critical points and what are they? max. or min.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

$$f(x,y)=xy+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} \tag1$$

$$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(xy+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right)=y-\frac{1}{x^2}=0$$

Gives: $$y=\frac{1}{x^2} \tag2$$

$$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(xy+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right)=x-\frac{1}{y^2}=0$$

Gives $$x=\frac{1}{y^2}$$

Which leads to $y^2=\frac{1}{x}$

Using (2) with the above result we have the system:

$$y=\frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$y^2=\frac{1}{x}$$

This system has a single real solution $x=1$. Which implies, $y=1$

Now we have 1 critical point (1,1).

To determine whether this point is max. or min. you take the 2nd partial derivative w.r.t $x,y$ and test it using (1,1)

$$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(y-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=\frac{2}{x^3}$$

$$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(x-\frac{1}{y^2}\right)=\frac{2}{y^3}$$

We now need to determine the type of the extreme using the following test where (a,b) is the extreme point, that is (1,1) in this case:

$$v=\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial \:x^2}f\left(a,b\right).\frac{\partial \:^2}{\partial \:\:y^2}f\left(a,b\right)-\left[f\left(a,b\right)\right]^2$$

$$v(1,1)=2*2-9=-5$$

Since $v(1,1)<0$, all we can say is that the point (1,1) is a [Saddle Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point).

Comment: Note: Second rule test is ref. from here:https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=hcugW8A7cB8C&pg=PA957&dq=calculus+multi+variables+saddle+point&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimxIq08uLkAhURxYUKHVYACCsQ6AEIPjAD#v=onepage&q=calculus%20multi%20variables%20saddle%20point&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Unless you extend the definition of your function to give it some value at the point $\ (0,0)\ $, that point is *not* a critical point of the function according to any of the commonly used definitions of that term, most of which require a critical point of a function *to lie within the domain of definition* of that function.

The expression $\ \displaystyle xy + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}\ $ is not defined whenever $\ x=0\ $ or $\ y=0\ $, and can have arbitrarily large or arbitrarily small values at points $\ (x,y)\ $ arbitrarily close to $\ (0,0)\ $, so no matter how you extend its definition to give it a value at $\ (0,0)\ $, that point cannot be either a maximum or a minimum. A point with these characteristics is called a [*singularity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)).