# can I "index" a function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have a function with two variables $f(x, y) = \frac{(x-y)^2}{y*(1-y)},$ where $x, y\in \Bbb R$, $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$.

And I have a bunch of data points $D =((x_1, y_1),(x_2, y_2),...(x_n, y_n), )$.

My goal is to find  $(x^*, y^*) = \arg\max_{(x_i,y_i)\in D}f(x_i,y_i)$

Since my dataset is really big, I'm wondering whether there is any smart way to find the maximum without evaluating every data point.

What can I do except for run a convex hull on my data $D$, and only select from the boundary points?

Comment: find $(x^*, y^*) = argmax_{(x_i,y_i)\in D}f(x,y)$ , i mean i can simply evaluate every one and find the maximum, but i'm more interested in any smart way that don't need to evaluate everyone

Comment: You seem to *know* the function $f(x,y)$ defined on $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ (if you mean to exclude the boundaries).   Indeed the function becomes arbitrarily large near $y=0$ and $y=1$ as the denominator approaches zero.  Once you find a point $(x_i,y_i)$ where the function's value is fairly large, you can exclude some of the points without calculation of the function's value.  You may have more of a software design issue, e.g. how to sort the points or otherwise facilitate the search.

Comment: Try plotting the function via a tool first. Then you could take the partial derivatives w.r.t. x, y, equate them to zero to get the critical points. Then you could examine those points to determine whether they represent a max. or min. Something like this maybe: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3350260/maximum-or-minimum-in-a-function/3350299#3350299

Comment: the critical line for minimum is `x=y`. not sure how would that help to find maximum [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-y%29%5E2%2F%28y*%281-y%29%29%2C+0%3Cx%3C1%2C+0%3Cy%3C1) maybe i can exclude the points where x=y

Answer (score 0):

Your function on $(0,1)^2$ looks something like this: 
[image: Plot of function]
Just by looking at your function we can see for $x = 0$ and $y \rightarrow 1^-$  we have $f(x,y)\rightarrow \infty$ and further that for $x=1$ and $y\rightarrow 0^+$ we have $f(x,y) \rightarrow \infty$. These observations are also confirmed by the above plot.

This indicates that for some given data $D\subset (0,1)^2$ the larger values of $f(x_i,y_i)$ would be the $(x_i,y_i)$ that are closer to the coordinates $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. Thus a simple improvement would be to only evaluate $f(x,y)$ on a subset of $D$ that are close to these coordinates. An easily implementable example would be is to evaluate $f$ on the subsets $D \cap [0,a]\times [1-a,1]$ and $D \cap [1-b,1]\times [0,b]$ for some suitably small $a,b$ such that these intersections are non-empty. If you have loads of data and if it is uniformly distributed over $(0,1)^2$ then $a$ and $b$ could be taken very small.

There are cleverer things you could do to reduce the subset you compute $f$ over, however there is the balance between the computational investment in finding better subsets of $D$ and just evaluating $f$ over a good enough subset.